# Spring boot application is not creating fat (uber) jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm following the example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start

When I build the app, I'm not getting the fat jar with all the dependencies, but only a jar with the compiled classes of the project.

I paste the pom.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.baeldung</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-bootstrap</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spring-boot-bootstrap</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent-boot-2</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent-boot-2</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>cloud-gcp</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.name}-gcp</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>cloudfoundry</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <finalName>${project.name}-cf</finalName>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/cloud/config/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>autoconfiguration</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*LiveTest.java</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                                        <exclude>**/*IntTest.java</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/AutoconfigurationTest.java</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <test.mime>json</test.mime>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>thin-jar</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${thin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- Download the dependencies at build time -->
                                <id>resolve</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>resolve</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <inherited>false</inherited>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/cloud/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <servlet.version>4.0.0</servlet.version>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, and it's unclear exactly what your parent does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This made the job:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>
                            com.domain.Application
                        </mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Out of EVERYWHERE on the internet this is the only place that clarifies how to correctly build the uber jar (something that happens by default if the spring boot parent POM is being used. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This was the piece missing in Spring documentation to use Spring without a parent: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent (hope they will update the documentation with your answer)

Answer (score 0):

to have the fat jar you can use following tag after dependencies.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

That is the only thing I used every time to have executable jar files with all dependencies included